# What is "comparative Google searches" in Site Self-Evaluation?

Tags: support, feature-request

I clicked on "site self-evaluation" and generally understand the idea.

However, I think the text needs some explanation.

> Run comparative Google searches on these questions

I think I'm quite good in internet technology, however "comparative search" is a black magic for me.

PS. Yeah -- You can say I can search what "comparative search", however it seems that it is not that clear. The first link in [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=comparative+search) leads [here](http://www.hitsplitter.com/). In my opinion some words more would be perfect, how to perform this and what one gets.

Comment: What the sentence is trying to say is: If you put the question's keywords in Google, how does our content compare with other results? For example how does the results when searching for ["did robin hood exist"](https://www.google.gr/search?q=did+robin+hood+exist&oq=did+robin+hood+exist&aqs=chrome.0.69i57.11935j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) compare with the answers on [Is there any proof that Robin Hood existed?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14/is-there-any-proof-that-robin-hood-existed)

Comment: The phrasing is confusing, "comparative searches" makes it sound like a special Google tool when there isn't one. I'm on mobile now and can't type a full answer (tiny screen), I'll try to give you a more thorough answer later in the afternoon (if there isn't an answer since then).

Comment: Apparently they expect that one will spend ten minutes on each of the ten "site review" Q & A's to run a web search and compare and contrast the top-ranked hits of the search to the SE content. LOL I have no time for that. I have a fairly good idea of what well-sourced, well-written answers to factual questions should look like and I used this internal yardstick to compare against. Thirty seconds per question is enough. (If anyone is interested, I rated most "satisfactory" with only one or two "Needs work" or "Excellent".)